# How to configure SCM (gitHub) checkout re-try in multibranch declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

My multibranch declarative Jenkins pipeline is failing very frequently during SCM checkout with timeout error and it works after one or two retries. is there anyway to automate the retry the SCM checkout?

**Jenkinsfile**

```
agent {
    label "agent1"
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        parallel {
            stage('Test1') {
                steps { sh 'echo Test 1 passed' }
            }
            stage('Test2') {
                steps {
                    sh 'echo Test2 is passed'
                }
            } stage('Test3') {
                steps {
                    sh 'echo Test 3 passed'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add wrapper steps such as "retry" to retry the SCM checkout step.

```
agent {
    label "agent1"
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        parallel {
            stage('Test1') {
                steps {
                    retry(3) {
                        echo "Test 1 passed"
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Test2') {
                steps {
                    retry(3) {
                        echo "Test 1 passed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added Jenkins multi branch configuration setting for Git Checkout not in jenkinsfile.

Comment: @ArjunS As far as I know there is no retry step for branch source checkout. But you can set the timeout period though. Set a longer timeout period. Also try to see the logs to find out why it is getting timed out.